# Getting JsonIgnore or JsonIgnoreProperties to work on servlet filter

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

The Java object has to be serialized into a json string in the servlet filter for a jersey application.

Have the following object,

```
 @XmlRootElement
 @JsonIgnoreProperties({"bar"})
 public class Foo{
    String a="1";

    String b="2";

    @JsonIgnore
    String bar="3";

    };



      ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
      om.writeValueAsString(fooObject);
```

returns,

```
        {
          a:"1",
          b:"2",
          bar:"3" // Inspite of Jsonignore and jsonignoreproperties bar is returned
          }
```

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the imports to fasterxml from codehaus and adding the following feature to the mapper fixed the issue.

```
      mapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use @XmlTransient:

```
@XmlTransient
String bar="3";
```